# Exiting a loop when a non-double input is typed

Tags: c

Basically the title, I am in a beginners C++ class and am trying to do an assignment but have been having trouble learning without the hands on teaching due to covid. I am trying to sum and average numbers using a while loop, but have it stop when a character or string is entered instead of a double. I think all of my code except the conditionals work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    double userNum, numSum, numAvg;
    int i;              //iterations for calculating average
    userNum = 0.0;
    numSum = 0.0;
    numAvg = 0.0;
    i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (1) {
            printf("Enter a score (or stop to quit):\n");
            scanf("%lf", &userNum);
        }
        else  // I thought this would break the loop if any nun double value was entered but I was wrong?
        {
            break;
        }
        numSum = numSum + userNum;
        i++;

    }
    if (i == 0)            // if no ittereations done, gives no sum message
    {
        printf("No sum and average calculated!");
    }
    else
    {
                           // otherwise calculates and prints sum and avg
    }
    {
        numAvg = numSum / i;
        printf("The sum is: %0.2lf, average is: %0.2lf", numSum, numAvg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would the `else` branch of `if(1)` ever be entered?

Comment: *"I am in a beginners C++ class"* - hmm, the code you post looks more like C, not C++.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: You want to do something different (like exit the loop) when the user types something other than a properly formed number.  That's good.  Now, what's doing the parsing of the user's input?  `scanf`.  So if `scanf` fails to parse the number, you need `scanf` to tell you that somehow.  But it does!  `scanf` returns the number of inputs that it successfully collected.  You called `scanf("%lf")`, so you asked it to read one thing.  In this case, `scanf` will return 1 if it read that one thing, and 0 (or EOF) if it didn't.

Answer (score 4):

`if(1)` is redundant and by adding it, you are never going to reach `else`.

It is equivalent to `if (1 != 0)` which is always true.

You can achieve what you are asking by checking the return value of `scanf()`. You can modify your code like so:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("Enter a score (or stop to quit):\n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &userNum) != 1) // should return 1 if 1 double is read
    {
        break;
    }
    numSum = numSum + userNum;
    i++;

}
```

For large inputs, I would suggests that you switch to `fgets()` and later parse the string with `sscanf()`. `scanf()` doesn't provide any protection from arithmetic overflow, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: This makes so much sense thank you, I didn't realize I wasn't equating the scanf to the conditional and was just instead relating it to the function.